# Advice on Scheduling/Time Management for Part-Time PhD

Tags: phd, time-management, part-time

So, I'm embarking on a part-time PhD. I'm doing it part-time primarily because I have a very well paying job that I enjoy and don't want to give up. Those are tough to come by in this day and age after-all.

Consequently, I'm anticipating my PhD taking about 6 years for lit review and experimental work and then another two to write up my final thesis. I'm 23, that time-scale is equivalent to roughly 1/4 of my life lived so far and thus I've never really had to plan and organise anything of this scale before.

As such, I'm concerned about making sure I schedule this well, for two reasons:

1. I have a propensity to overwork, I've suffered from chronic burnout in the past and I don't want to go there again. So I need to pace myself.
2. On the exact opposite foot, I need to make sure I don't end up sticking it so far on the backburner that I never get it finished.

My initial thoughts to manage this are to set myself 6 monthly goals and try to stick to these. However, I am concerned that this may make adapting to changes harder or I might make the goals too large / too small and run into the same problems as above.

I'd appreciate any advice anyone has that's pertinent to this particular question. Obviously scheduling for a full-time PhD is a challenge in itself, but I'm trying to fit a part-time PhD around a full time job, so I need to get this aspect right if I'm going to make it work.

If it's of relevance, my PhD is in the areas of satellite and opto-electronic  engineering.

Comment: Have you talked to your supervisor about this? And have you checked to see if your university has specific support for part-time PhDs (many do)?

Comment: This is not really an answer but I think in your situation communication is very important. Talk to your supervisor often (for full time this could be once a week; you will need to scale that appropriately) even if you haven't made any progress since your last meeting (especially if you haven't made progress). Also talk often with other PhD students in your department/university, especially if they are also working part time. It's nice to commiserate about the difficulties of research every now and then.

Comment: @astronat - I'll give that a go, thank you